# signed two's complement arithmetic

Tags: c, types

I was thinking on data types ranges, a question arises. 
As we know signed char's range is from -128 to 127. 
I got the how 127 comes, i.e. 0111111 = +127

But I could not get how -128 comes? 
if we just ON sign bit we get 11111111, how its is equal to -128 ?

Answer (score 8):

Most of the time, computers use what's called **2's complement** to represent signed integers.

The way 2's complement works is that the possible values are in a huge loop, from 0, to MAX_VALUE, to MIN_VALUE, to zero, and so on.

So the minimum value is the maximum value +1 - `01111111 = 127`, and `10000000 = -128`.

This has the nice property of behaving exactly the same as unsigned arithmetic - if I want to do `-2 + 1`, I have `11111110 + 00000001 = 11111111 = -1`, using all the same hardware as for unsigned addition.

The reason there's an extra value on the low end is that we choose to have all numbers with the high-bit set be negative, which means that 0 takes a value away from the positive side.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that there *is* a representation where `11111111` is the minimum representable number, and it is indeed -127 - this is "sign-magnitude" form.  In sign-magnitude, there are two zeroes - a `+0` and a `-0`, `00000000` and `10000000` respectively.

Comment: @Asad Hanif, do you need more help? If this or another answer was helpful to you and answered your question, please don't forget to accept that answer. Also see [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)"? and [Why is voting important](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote)?

Answer (score 2):

In [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations#Two.27s_complement), -128 is 10000000.

Answer (score 0):

Negative numbers have the sign bit set to 1; `-128` is the value with the sign bit set but no other bits (i.e., it is the smallest negative number).  The binary representation of `-128` is `10000000`.  For other data lengths, the smallest negative number in two's complement is always `1000...` for the correct number of zeros.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to think of this is to start at 01111111 and then keep subtracting 1 until it wraps around; the previous value is the smallest negative value. Subtracting 1 from 00000000 using the standard "borrow" technique yields 11111111, which is indeed the binary representation for -1. We can keep subtracting down to 10000000, which is -128, and subtracting one more yields 01111111 again, wrapping around.